# Scraping large number of pages (full website) with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap the full web page with python and selenium.
I'm providing the website URL (i.e. https://example.com) which then will scrap the homepage and then it will continue doing this recursively for all subpages by getting the links from the first page. I'm facing serious performance issues as the number of pages can exceed 500 and the selenium will stop in the middle of the execution.

FYI I'm using Selenium as I need to scan JS-based web pages (where content is being generated by JavaScript). Are there any best practices on how to Scrap the full web page content more efficiently? or other similar libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` module,

The code below will run multiple selenium scraping processes parallelly

```
def product_parser(product_links):

    # your selenium code

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH,
        options=chrome_options,
    )
    ........
    ........


# create a list of 10 lists with product links
list_chunked_product_links = [[], [], [],......[]]  

# an example, it will create a list of 10 lists consists of max 1000 elements each
# [product_links[x:x + 1000] for x in range(0, len(product_links) - 2, 1000)]


# run 10 drivers concurrently
def run_all(product_links):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(product_parser, product_links)


def main_func():
    start_time = time.time()
    t_start = time.localtime()
    run_all(list_chunked_product_links)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"start time : {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', t_start)}, \n End Time : {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ")
    print(f"Scraped {len(product_links)} in {duration} seconds")
```

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions. I think threading will significantly improve the performance but it will do it by using more resources which might be a huge problem for large websites with 500+ pages (it can kill the server). Just wanted to know if you did this with large web apps and what was the results?

Comment: I had to set a cron job which which restarts the script once a week. Used 10 workers.